# How to send json using @RequestBody without using domain object

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

I am building project `REST project` with `Spring Boot` and i come across an issue of sending JSON from client to server.
My Scenerio is i want to send json like this using postman REST client:

```
{
"test":"success"
}
```

And want to get this json using this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> postData(@RequestBody Map map){
        log.info("in test Connection method");
        return map;
    }
```

I am using above method but it is giving `exception`.

If it is not possible to process `json` data with `@RequestBody` with `POST` request then is there any other way to get json data with `POST` request and process that json data?

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested it here and it works fine.

You have to specify the `Content-Type` header in your POST request though, and set it to `application/json`. You can easily do this in Postman in the Headers tab.`

Without it you will most likely get an Internal Server Error (500) saying

> Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported